# How to avoid short-circuit operation without using bitwise operators

Tags: c#, operators

I am trying to see if there is a better way of writing the following:

```
if ((DirectoryDetailsPath == null) & (FileDetailsPath == null))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Error: Path for 'Directory' or 'File' has to be specified.");

}
```

without using the Bitwise "&" operator.  I would perfer using the logical operators, but becuase of short-circuit I am unable to evaluate both fields.

I only want to see an error if both fields are "null".

Thanks

Comment: *Why* do you want to evaluate both, if you know the result after the first? And if you really need to evaluate both, why don't you want to use `&`?

Comment: The only reason to evaluate both is if they have some side-effect, which is poor programming style.  In which case, the methods should be evaluated first and then their results checked in the condition

Comment: `bool operator&(bool a, bool b)` is not actually defined as a 'bitwise' operator. Though the point is academic and it is frequently called bitwise.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to evalaute both becuase my condition is to show the error only if both values are null.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @PranavShah: But once you've seen that the first expression isn't null, you *know* that you won't show the error message - so why bother evaluating the second expression?

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right.  I think I was just over-thinking and confusing myself.

Comment: You weren't over-thinking, you were just confusing the functionality of && vs ||.  No biggie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I only want to see an error if both fields are "null".*

Then try using `&&`:

```
if ((DirectoryDetailsPath == null) && (FileDetailsPath == null))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Error: Path for 'Directory' or 'File' has to be specified.");

}
```

---

More information:

The above solution will short-circuit if the first condition is false.   This still satisfies the requirement of only writing the output if both values are null.

Comment: @MystereMan Sorry Sorry, my bad :)

Comment: @Jeff this will cause a short-cirucit and will show the output as soon as it evaluates "(DirectoryDetailsPath == null)".  If this first check is true it will not go to the second, and I need to test both

Comment: +1 - && Will short-circuit as soon as it hits a False... and will therefore return false, *which is what you want*.  || Will short-circuit as soon as it hits a True, which is what the question-asker is probably accidentally expecting of the &&, and would be an understandable confusion.  So in short, Khan's answer is correct.

Comment: @Khan The downvote was probably because you are wrong and the OP is correct. `&&` *will* short circuit as soon as the first operand is true.

Comment: @PranavShah You weren't overthinking or confusing yourself. You are right. Short circuiting *is* occurring in the example Khan has provided. It is possible that this is what you actually want, but short circuiting is definitely occurring. The second expression is never evaluated if the first one is true.

Comment: @Asad The answer is correct, there was incorrect information in the comments which I removed.

Comment: @Khan The answer still isn't correct, since it doesn't answer the question the OP asked. The OP is asking "How to **avoid short-circuit operation** without using bitwise operators", which you have not demonstrated in your answer. cadrell0's answer is correct and addresses the question.

Comment: @Asad That is where the "overthinking" came into play.  The criteria is "I only want to see an error if both fields are 'null'"

Comment: @Khan I just noticed that bit. The question is flawed; the title is different from the body.

Answer (score 2):

If you really must evaluate both conditions and don't want to use the bitwise operator, do it outside of the `if` statement.

```
bool isDirectoryDetailsPathNull = DirectoryDetailsPath == null;
bool isFileDetailsPathNull = FileDetailsPath == null;

if (isDirectoryDetailsPathNull && isFileDetailsPathNull)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Path for 'Directory' or 'File' has to be specified.");
}
```

However, there is really no point in this.  The compiler will probably decide to inline the variables, effectively giving you this, which is what you said you don't want.

```
if ((DirectoryDetailsPath == null) && (FileDetailsPath == null))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Path for 'Directory' or 'File' has to be specified.");
}
```